# Custom component not displaying in tab on Lightning Record Page when using mobile

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app

I have a Lightning Component which is inside tabs on my Lightning Record Page for *Contact* object. There are 3 tabs: *Details*, *Related Lists* and *myCustomComponent*.

The problem is that while in the mobile app, *myCustomComponent* tab is not being displayed, while other 2 tabs are displayed correctly.

According to [Lightning Record Page docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_app_builder_customize_lex_pages.htm&type=5):

> Lightning app and record pages available in: both the Salesforce mobile app and Lightning Experience

*myCustomComponent* header looks like this:

```html
    <aura:component
        implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome"
        access="global"
        controller="myCustomController">
```

Unfortunately, my Lightning Record Page is currently assigned only to Desktop form as Org Default and it is not possible to add it to the Phone form. How could I enable this Record Page to be also visible to mobile users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research I found out that *Salesforce1* app uses the standard compact page layout as defined in the Page Layout Editor, not a Lightning Page that can be edited in **Lightning App Builder**. The Page Layout Editor **doesn't support adding Lightning components**.

You can create custom Lightning pages and add them to the Salesforce1 navigation, but they aren't the same as the Lightning Experience pages that you see in the desktop version.

The workaround is to use a **Quick Action** to open the custom Lightning Component.